# unicode not being interpreted as unicode in Python

Tags: python

I've saved in a textfile a unicode string of this format 
    b'\x1e\x80E\xd7\xd4M\x94\xa8\xb4\xf3bl[^'
but when I read it from this external textfile, it gets read as a normal string.

I've tried reading the file in binary form, such as 
    open(celesi_file_path,"rb")

```
fciphertext = open(ciphertext_file_path, "rb")
fkey = open(celesi_file_path,"rb")
celesi = fkey.read()
ciphertext = fciphertext.read()
ciphertext = ciphertext.decode('latin-1')
celesi = celesi.decode('latin-1')
print(type(celesi))
print(type(ciphertext))
print(celesi)
print(ciphertext)
```

The output is a string as: 
    "b'\x1e\x80E\xd7\xd4M\x94\xa8\xb4\xf3bl[^'" 
while I am expecting it to be a string of characters which are not in this format

Comment: How did you write this string to the file?

Comment: I first converted a ciphertext to string, such as  *ciphertext_to_be_written = str(ciphertext)* and then I used *fc.write(path,ciphertext,encoding='utf-8')*, but when I read it it is read just like a normal string @ForceBru

Comment: "I first converted a ciphertext to string", so basically read's it as a string.

Comment: @BleronQorri, you wrote a string, and you read out a string, so there's no problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
>>> data = b'\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82'
>>> str(data)
"b'\\xd0\\x9f\\xd1\\x80\\xd0\\xb8\\xd0\\xb2\\xd0\\xb5\\xd1\\x82'"
```

So, if you wrote `str(data)` to the file, you wrote the slashes and `x`s, literally. You didn't write the *bytes*, you wrote the string *representation* of these bytes provided by Python. You wrote, in this example, *51 bytes* (!) instead of the original 12.

You should've written the bytes themselves:

```
with open("data.bin", "wb") as f:
    f.write(data)
```

And then open this file in binary mode as well and read the bytes.